# session variable get lossed during reloading of page in java

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

how to permanently save the value of session variable even after reloading of (view_blog_comment)page??

I am working over a major project (using language java)...in which i have module(blog).The working of blog is such that...when we click on a link on main page...i.e. blog...blog.jsp pages get open...then there are 3 link-
1. create blog
2. view Others blog
3. view own Blog

when we click on view Others Blog...in that(viewOtherBlog.jsp) page we can view all others blog...with there title and content...i have made the title as hyperlink like this...
Blog title -->

"><%=rs.getString(2) %>

when we click on this title we jump to another page..where we get detailed view of blog.After jumping to new page there we get detailed information about that blog...with the option of Commenting a blog and posted comment can also be viewed below.

Every thing is all write until...Comment post button is not clicked...
When button is clicked....page reloads..after page reloading  - Title and Content details are lossed.

(view_Blog.jsp)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import='java.sql.*'%>

<% 

  HttpSession s=request.getSession();
  String uid=(String)s.getAttribute("u_id");



 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:
//localhost:3306/major_db","root", "root");
%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>


    <%
  try
    {

    PreparedStatement p1=conn.prepareStatement("select * from blog where pid !=   '"+uid+"' ");
     ResultSet rs=p1.executeQuery();

    %>



              <% while(rs.next()==true)
                           {

               %>
           <table>
                <tr>
            <td>Blog Author --></td>
                   <td>
                   <%=rs.getString(5)%>   
                   </td>
          </tr>                         
          <tr>

           <td>Blog title --></td>
   <td><a href="blog_read_comment.jsp?bid=<%=rs.getInt(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
        //when above link is clicked the value is stored in bid
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Blog Content --></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
        </tr>
        <% 

                   }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     out.println(e);
 }

 %>
    </table>       
</body>
</html>




    </table>       
    </body>
    </html>
```

(read_blog_comment.jsp)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import='java.io.PrintWriter' %>
<%@page import='java.sql.*'%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import='javax.servlet.http.HttpSession' %>


<% 
String b_id=request.getParameter("bid");//value of bid is stored in b_id
HttpSession s=request.getSession();//session is created to ]
//permanently save the value of bid
s.setAttribute("b_id",b_id);
String bid=(String)s.getAttribute("b_id");
problem is in above 4 lines....


 //value of bid 
//is lost when page gets reloaded
//i am not able to understand why this happens
//becoz of this problem when i comment on the blog the blog_name,blog_content is lost

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/major_db",   "root", "root");
%>


<% 


     try
     {

        PreparedStatement p1=conn.prepareStatement("select * from
        blog where   bid='"+bid+"';");
        ResultSet rs=p1.executeQuery();

%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <% if(rs.next()==true)
                           {
                               %>
        <tr>

            <td><h4>Blog title</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Blog Content</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
        </tr>
        <% 
        }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     out.println("Exception"+e);
 }

 %>
 </table>


 <form action="blog_Comment_Servlet" method="post">
     <h3> Post a Comment </h3>
     <textarea name="post_comment" required="required" 
     id="post-comment" rows="3"    cols="50">
     </textarea>
     <input  type="submit" id="button-submit" value="Post" name="submit"  />        
 </form>


 <%
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement p1=conn.prepareStatement("select * from 
        blog_comment where bid='"+bid+"';");
        ResultSet rs=p1.executeQuery();
  %>
  <table border="0"> 
      <label>Comments:</label>

       <% 
        while(rs.next())
         {

       %>
        <tr>

            <td><h4>By-</h4></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(6) %></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(5) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Comment - </h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
        </tr>


        <%      
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("Exception - "+e);
    }
     %>
   </table>


   </body>
</html>
```

(blog_comment_servlet coding)

```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@page import='java.io.PrintWriter' %>
   <%@page import='java.sql.*'%>
   <%@page import="java.util.*" %>
   <%@page import='javax.servlet.http.HttpSession' %>


 <% 
 String b_id=request.getParameter("bid");
 HttpSession s=request.getSession();
 s.setAttribute("b_id",b_id);
 String bid=(String)s.getAttribute("b_id");

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:
 //localhost:3306/major_db",    "root", "root");
 %>


 <% 


     try
     {

        PreparedStatement p1=conn.prepareStatement("select * from 
        blog where bid='"+bid+"';");
        ResultSet rs=p1.executeQuery();

   %>


   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>

    <body>

    <table>
        <% if(rs.next()==true)
                           {
                               %>
        <tr>

            <td><h4>Blog title</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Blog Content</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
        </tr>
        <% 
        }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     out.println("Exception"+e);
 }

 %>
 </table>


 <form action="blog_Comment_Servlet" method="post">
     <h3> Post a Comment </h3>
     <textarea name="post_comment" required="required"
      id="post-comment" rows="3" cols="50">
                </textarea>
         <input  type="submit" id="button-submit" value="Post" name="submit"  />        
 </form>


 <%
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement p1=conn.prepareStatement("select * from 
        blog_comment where bid='"+bid+"';");
        ResultSet rs=p1.executeQuery();
  %>
  <table border="0"> 
      <label>Comments:</label>

       <% 
        while(rs.next())
         {

       %>
        <tr>

            <td><h4>By-</h4></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(6) %></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(5) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Comment - </h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
        </tr>


        <%      
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("Exception - "+e);
    }
%>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, where is the problem? What line?

Comment: Make your problem clear please .. !

Comment: when the code is executed for the 1st time then every thing is right...but when blog is commented,value of bid is lost.